# Swift Passing Closure With Params

Tags: ios, closures, block, swift

Currently I'm passing in a closure as a property on an object that accepts no params and has no return value as follows:

```
class MyClass {
    var myClosureProperty: (() -> ())? {
            didSet {
                doSomeActionWhenClosureIsSet()
            }
    }
}

var instanceOfMyClass = MyClass()
instanceOfMyClass.myClosureProperty = {
    // do some things here...
}
```

and so far this is working great. I want to be able to pass in a parameter when setting this closure to be used inside the instance of MyClass. I'm looking for SOMETHING like below, although the syntax I'm sure is incorrect:

```
class MyClass {
    var myClosureProperty: ((newString: String) -> ())? {
            didSet {
                doSomeActionWhenClosureIsSet(newString)
            }
    }

    func doSomeActionWhenClosureIsSet(stringParam: String) -> () {
        // create a button with the stringParam title...
    }
}

var instanceOfMyClass = MyClass()
instanceOfMyClass.myClosureProperty = {("Action")
    exampleFunction()
}
```

How would I go about passing in a parameter to this closure that can be used inside of MyClass - i.e. a value that can be used inside the didSet portion of the property itself as in the second example?

EDIT: Here's what ended up working for me:

```
class MyClass {
        var myClosurePropertyWithStringAndAction: (buttonName: String, closure: (() -> ()))? {
            didSet {
                  let buttonTitle = myClosurePropertyWithStringAndAction!.buttonName
                  createButtonWithButtonTitle(buttonTitle)
            }
         }

        func createButtonWithButtonTitle(buttonTitle: String) -> () {
             // here I create a button with the buttonTitle as the title and set
             // handleButtonPressed as the action on the button
        }

        func handleButtonPressed() {
            self.myClosurePropertyWithStringAndAction?.closure()
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how I call it on the instance:

```
instaceOfMyClass.myClosurePropertyWithStringAndAction = ("Done", {
    // do whatever I need to here
})
```

Comment: Are you simply looking for the syntax of defining a closure with in put params? Your question is a bit unclear

Comment: Sorry, hit backspace while editing and it took my BACK a page and when I came back some changes weren't there.. Let me edit my post with the actual question.

Comment: I think there are some logistic problems with what you're trying to do...`newString` is the name of an input paramater to the closure. The value is **unknown** when you set the closure. There is no way your `didSet` can access it because that value will be passed in when you call the closure and actually execute it.

Comment: On that same note, when you're setting `myClosureProperty`, it doesn't make sense to be passing in `SUCCESS` to the closure, because you are not calling it, you are just defining the closure.

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do, maybe it will make more sense, perhaps my choice of strings with "Success" was confusing... I want to pass a string and an action to MyClass. When I SET the closure property on the instance of MyClass, I'd like to call a function that creates a button using that string as the title, and when the button is pressed I want the action defined in the closure to be run. In the above example, when MyClass appears on screen (a UIView), I'd like there to be a button saying "Action" to be there, and when that button is pressed the function exampleFunction() is called.

Comment: See my comment on that answer, this calls your closure and runs `functionThatRunsWhenButtonIsPressed()` once right when you set it. Then, the button will call it again. Weird behavior if you ask me

Comment: I don't want it to be run when it is set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55579/discussion-between-mike-and-jack-wu).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are trying to set pass 2 things, a closure AND a button name, you won't be able to do that with a simple setter to the closure.

The constraint you have is that these 2 things are dependent on each other, so you must either set both or none.

First of all, adding `newString` to your closure isn't doing what you think it does. Its a parameter so you can pass a string to your closure when you call it, it **isn't** a way to pass in a string when you define the closure.

A "Swift way" to do what you want might be to define it as a tuple. You can name the values inside a tuple so it would work how you want it. Try it like this:

```
class MyClass {
    var stringAndClosure: (buttonName: String,closure: (() -> ()))? {
        didSet {
            //create button named buttonName
            let name = stringAndClosure!.buttonName
        }
    }
}

let instanceOfMyClass = MyClass()
instanceOfMyClass.stringAndClosure =  ("Action",{ exampleFunction() })
```

Comment: This might be more appropriate, I'll test it out.

Comment: I'm getting a use of unresolved identifier error trying to access buttonName inside didSet...

Comment: @Mike since its an optional, you have to unwrap it, I'll edit

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `in` keyword to pass parameters in a closure

```
{ (someString: String) -> Bool in
    //do something with someString
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't think is possible... You can do like this instead :

```
class MyClass{
    var myClosureProperty: (() -> String)?
    {
        didSet
        {
            doSomeActionWhenClosureIsSet(myClosureProperty!())
        }
    }
    func doSomeActionWhenClosureIsSet(stringParam: String) -> ()
    {
        println("it worked: " + stringParam) // hopefully this would print "it worked: SUCCESS"
    }
}
```

Comment: This did it for me, I'll add an edit with more specific implementation, even though it seems a bit counterintuitive - it worked...

Comment: @Mike Maybe I misunderstood your purpose...but this calls your closure immediately after you set it. Is that what you want? This answer uses the return value of your closure, which I'm not sure is what you want because you want to create a button that calls the closure, from what I understand

Comment: @Jack Wu answer look better for me :)